# How to manage this Github workflow - not adding all directories within a project I want to post

Tags: git, github, push, commit, addition

I'm a total noob at Github (just getting started) and I want to create a new repository with almost everything I have locally.  My local file structure is:

```
project name to post on github
  **assets**
  css
  images
  index.html
  other_html_files.html
  README.txt
  scripts
```

I want to post everything **but** assets.  That directory contains design assets, photoshop and illustrator files.  Unneeded for the github push as well as being a waste of bandwidth as those are larger files.  I do want to keep that directory with the **local** project folder just because it's easier to manage for me (I want everything together).  I just don't want to add/commit/push that **assets** directory to github.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty simple fix.  See [this link](http://spheredev.org/wiki/Git_for_the_lazy), particularly the part about .gitignore, where you can list files and entire directories.  Also, don't forget to list .gitignore in .gitignore.

Comment: I don't seem to have .gitignore. -bash: .gitignore: command not found

Comment: right, you don't.  you have to make it.  %vi .gitignore.  it's a file that you create by that name and that name alone, and git will recognize it.  in the link i posted, "nano .gitignore" is calling the text editor "nano", therefore creating the file.

Answer (score 0):

.gitignore file

```
**assets**/
```

then just do

```
git add *
git commit -u "blah"
```

with gitignore in place "git add" will skip over that directory.

Comment: I don't seem to have .gitignore.  -bash: .gitignore: command not found